# array_agg with IF / BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables: site logs and reviews sites.

site logs table:

```
ID  ID_site Status    Timestamp
1   1       denied     1/1/2022
2   1       pending    2/1/2022
3   2       pending    2/1/2022
```

reviews sites table:

```
ID        ID_site    review_timestamp   
1          1         1/12/2021
2          1         2/1/2022
3          2         2/1/2022
```

I need to add an attribute in the review table that indicates if that revision is a fix review or not.
If the site has a status of denied before the review date, it is a fix review.

The expected result:

```
ID_site review_timestamp    is_fix_review
1       1/12/2021           FALSE
1       2/1/2022            TRUE
2       2/1/2022            FALSE
```

My query is:

```
select 
ID_site,
review_timestamp,
array_agg(if((b.status ='denied' and b.timestamp<a.review_timestamp), true, false)
big
order by if(b.status ='denied', b.timestamp, null) desc limit 1)

[offset(0)] is_fix_review



from reviews_table a 

left join site_logs_table b
on a.ID_site=b.ID_site



group by 
ID_site,
review_timestamp,
is_fix_review
```

The message error is:
Column is_fix_review contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select any_value(a.ID_site) ID_site, 
  any_value(review_timestamp) review_timestamp, 
  ifnull(array_agg(Status order by Timestamp desc limit 1)[offset(0)] = 'denied', false) is_fix_review
from reviews a
left join logs b
on a.ID_site = b.ID_site
and review_timestamp > Timestamp
group by format('%t', a)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Gives me everything false.
Something I didn't say is that the site may have several denied